# Mutiple Meyda analyzers not possible: library issue or problem in my implementation?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Ok, I'm using Meyda, a library for extracting audio features, in a Electron project. To handle everything related to audio in this project I implemented an `Audio()` class. Summarizing, I get the audio track, splitt it in left and right channels and merge it again. For each channel, there will be a Meyda analyzer extracting features. A simplified code, that shows only meyda sending data to a spectrogram graph object, would be:

```
class Audio {
    constructor(audioElementID, spectrogramObj) {
        const audioContext = new AudioContext();

        this.audioElement = document.getElementById(audioElementID);

        const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(this.audioElement);
        const splitter = audioContext.createChannelSplitter(2);

        track.connect(splitter);

        this.gainNode = {
            master: audioContext.createGain(),
            left: audioContext.createGain(),
            right: audioContext.createGain()
        };

        splitter.connect(this.gainNode.left, 0);
        splitter.connect(this.gainNode.right, 1);

        const merger = audioContext.createChannelMerger(2);

        this.gainNode.left.connect(merger, 0, 0);
        this.gainNode.right.connect(merger, 0, 1);

        merger.connect(this.gainNode.master);

        this.gainNode.master.connect(audioContext.destination);

        // first analyzer
        this.analyzerLeft = Meyda.createMeydaAnalyzer({
            'audioContext': audioContext,
            'source': this.gainNode.left,
            'bufferSize': 1024,
            'featureExtractors': ['amplitudeSpectrum'],
            'callback': features => {

                spectrogramObj.left.updatePlot(features.amplitudeSpectrum);

            }
        });

       // second analyzer
       this.analyzerRight = Meyda.createMeydaAnalyzer({
            'audioContext': audioContext,
            'source': this.gainNode.right,
            'bufferSize': 1024,
            'featureExtractors': ['amplitudeSpectrum'],
            'callback': features => {

                spectrogramObj.right.updatePlot(features.amplitudeSpectrum);

            }
        });

    }

    play() {
        this.audioElement.play();
        this.analyzerLeft.start();
        this.analyzerRight.start();
    };

    pause() {
        this.audioElement.pause();
        this.analyzerLeft.stop();
        this.analyzerRight.stop();
    };

}

module.exports.Audio = Audio;
```

As you see, I correctly named both analyzer differently. Problem is: only the last analyzer works. It's seems actually that `analyzerLeft` and `analyzerRight` are all ponting to the last analyzer created. If I add a third one, named `thirdAnalyzer` and in the method `play()` **DO NOT** write `this.thirdAnalyzer.start()`, the third one will be started even so, and only it.

Is this a library issue or something related to Class implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell it looks like Meyda only allows one MeydaAnalyzer at a time. When you create a new instance of the MeydaAnalyzer with the [factory method](https://github.com/meyda/meyda/blob/master/src/main.js#L160) it receives the Meyda object itself as a second parameter. MeydaAnalyzer does use this object to attach all the values to it. Whenever you create the next MeydaAnalyzer it will simply overwrite the previous values.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature. But since you already filed an issue we will surely find out soon. :-)

In the meantime you can work around this issue by copying the internal reference to the Meyda object directly after you created a new MeydaAnalyzer. This will for example make sure that each instance of the MeydaAnalyzer uses a different ScriptProcessorNode.

```
this.analyzerLeft = Meyda.createMeydaAnalyzer({
    // ...
});

this.analyzerLeft._m = { ...this.analyzerLeft._m };
```

But keep in mind that this hack uses a private class member of the MeydaAnalyzer class which may or may not disappear in a future version of Meyda.

Comment: It works, thanks for the commitment. Sadly, I think I'll have to give up the idea of two channels. The project: an app that controls two fisical LED panels (UDP protocol). The user plays a song and controls how the panels animate by some inputs. The app shows two spectrogram graphs (plotly.js) and two virtual panels (fabric.js) to help in the process. I implemented everything to the left side, but now turning the right side on the app gets really slow. Too much computation I think. I don't know, I'm very new to programming, is there anything I could do, not losing the real-time behavior?

Comment: I know there must be something, like when you watch youtube and the bar loads content ahead of what you are watching. But I don't know the terms. Something like computing "off-line" and storing.

Comment: There are always various ways one could try to improve the performance. If you know the audio data upfront you can try using an OfflineAudioContext. But using an AudioElement only allows Meyda to analyze the audio like a live input. You could alternatively try to increase the bufferSize to reduce the number of times when Meyda runs. You can also try to store the output from Meyda in a variable and only update the DOM in a requestAnimationFrame() callback to make sure that you don't update the DOM too often. There are so many options, it's hard to tell what could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Just a requestAnimationFrame() worked. Didn't know about this function. Pretty cool. Thanks mate.